# Headset is not working with Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, headset

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and from my speaker the sound is coming but after inserting the headset it's not working. I have tested my headset in windows XP and found no problem with it.
I have played with the volume control but never find any way to get it be done.

Could anybody help me out?
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go to your sound options (preferences) and choose your headset as output device.

[image]

Comment: I have not found any "audio headset analog stereo" option in sound Preferences..Now what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The following steps solved my problem.

- Go to `System Settings > Sounds`.
- Under the **Hardware** tab, check on whether your headset is detected.
- If detected: Go to the **input** tab and select the headset's name. Then, go to the **output** tab and select the headset name again. Adjust the volume of each to be audible.
- Try to listen to something.
- If not detected: Try using a USB adapter for your headset. Your sound port may be defective.